# Was Cameron jealous of Riley?

Tags: character, terminator-series, the-sarah-connor-chronicles

In *Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles* season 2, when John Connor starts a relationship with "Riley", Cameron seems to be upset. In **Episode 17 - "Ourselves Alone"** Cameron was trying to kill Riley, then John came and saved her. So my question is, why did Cameron act like this? Is this because of Riley getting close to John and John moving Cameron away? Is Cameron jealous about it (jealous of Riley)?